# Least square optimisation with two non-linear equal constraints

Tags: python, least-squares

I am looking for a way to solve the optimisation problem with two non-linear equal constraints.

My cost function is

```
E = 0
for n in range(1, N):
    E += (np.linalg.norm((x[:, i] - o - np.dot(x[:, i], a) * a)) - r) ** 2
```

My two non-linear equal constraints are

```
np.dot(a, o) = 0
np.linalg.norm(a) = 1
```

Can I use scipy.leastsq to solve this problem? How can I write the code?

Thank you

Update: I found minimize can solve the problem as state [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). However I met another problem.

I have the following code

```
(result, ier) = optimize.minimize(Step1CostFun, P, args=(S),
                                  method='Nelder-Mead',
                                  bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

where P constaints parameters that are going to be optimised, P.shape = (1, 7). S contains observation data, S.shape = (3, 51).

As for the constraints, I have

```
def DotConstraint(P):
(r, a1, a2, a3, o1, o2, o3) = P
return np.dot([a1, a2, a3], [o1, o2, o3])


def NormConstraint(P):
    (r, a1, a2, a3, o1, o2, o3) = P
    return np.linalg.norm([a1, a2, a3]) - 1

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': DotConstraint},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': NormConstraint})
```

However, I got an error that

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,7) (3,51)
```

Can anyone help to have a look? Thank you

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you. I will move it to there.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly where you're going wrong, but note that you don't need to pass extra args into your objective function, you can just have your objective function close over `x`.  Also, I was getting errors saying Nelder-Mead doesn't work with constraints.  It appears the only method that works with equality constraints is SLSQP.  Here's code that worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def DotConstraint(P):
    (r, a1, a2, a3, o1, o2, o3) = P
    return np.dot([a1, a2, a3], [o1, o2, o3])

def NormConstraint(P):
    (r, a1, a2, a3, o1, o2, o3) = P
    return np.linalg.norm([a1, a2, a3]) - 1

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': DotConstraint}, {'type': 'eq', 'fun': NormConstraint})

P = (1,0,0,1,2,0,0)

x = [np.array([3,0,1]), np.array([2,1,2]), np.array([1,0,3]), np.array([2, -1, 4]), np.array([2.6, 0.8, 5])]

def CostFunction(P):
    (r, a1, a2, a3, o1, o2, o3) = P
    a = np.array([a1, a2, a3])
    o = np.array([o1, o2, o3])
    return reduce(lambda i,j: i+j, map(lambda arr: (np.linalg.norm(arr - o - np.dot(arr,a)*a) - r)**2, x))

res = optimize.minimize(CostFunction, P, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
print res
```